# External Images Hosted on Amazon S3 Not Showing SSRS Report

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Hi I have a report which have Image in it. I have given the source of image a External Image and fully qualified URL. Images are deployed on Amazon S3 cloud service.

I am able to access the image from URL in browser without need of any credentials. But images are not shown on SSRS report.

I entered some other URL having .JPG file and it is showing in report but image on Amazon S3 is not shown.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Where are you deploying the report?  On an SSRS server?  Can you deploy the images into the SSRS server?

Comment: Do you have an execution account configured in the Configuration Manager? Have you tested from BIDS?

Comment: @CDC Yes i am deploying reports on SSRS server as well running from BIDS.

Comment: @SébastienSevrin Sevrin Yes i had that, but can u explain why we need it and which account and how it will help in accessing URL that is easily accesible through browser. Images are not coming in BIDS also.

Comment: "can u explain why we need it" => I was asking just to help diagnose. This account will only be used if credentials are needed to access your image, as specified [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181156.aspx). Now, to close the doors: if this account is currently configured and has logon rights, can you log on the report server with this account and access the image URL through your browser? Can you also confirm that you are not using a VPN?

Comment: "Images are not coming in BIDS also" => This is strange. Can you provide the formula you use for the external image source? (you can mask parts of the url, it is just to see the structure). If you use static fully qualified URLs the image should be displayed in BIDS.

Answer (score 0):

BIDS shows you the image correctly because It is you retrieving the img your as a windows user, but you need to set an account credentials in the ser ver configuration menú. Doesnt bids give to you any warning when running the preview about this topic forma the imagen? This is frequently struggling issue when calling external imgs when running the ser ver.